# Is Index and Match correct for what I am trying to do?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I am trying to do is setup a formula that would allow to find the next largest Nth in a row.

To get the largest Qty is used:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$J6,1,MATCH(MAX($B2:$J2,1),$B2:$J2,0)-1),"")}
```

However, I am stuck on the second largest value to populate. I thought using an Array may be the trick. Unfortunately I cant seem to remember how it ought to be coded. I tried using:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B2:$J6,1,MATCH(LARGE($B2:$J2,2),$B2:$J2,0)),"")}
```

Which doesn't seem to work and I can't wrap my finger around where I'm making the mistake.

**Example of how it needs to look after the formula**

[image: Example of how it needs to look after the formula.]

Comment: In your second formula, what are you trying to do with the a `lookup_array` of `$B7:$J6`  ?  I suspect you didn't copy/paste that formula since Excel would have rendered it `b6:j7`

Comment: Once you correct the error pointed out by @Ron, your formula works, and also *doesn't* need to be an array formula

Comment: I'm trying to get it populate with the next highest value. For example, for part number 10126 the two largest values would be for Oklahoma and Riverside, however, I'm having difficulties with the formula to grab the next Nth value. In my current worksheet it pulls Oklahoma & Oklahoma rather than Riverside.

Comment: @Ron I'm using the Array to look through the Plant Sites for the largest Nth and pull the data over. It would also appear that when I copied the formula from Excel I grabbed from K6 and M6.

Comment: That is how `LARGE` works.  You need to search for information on ranking when there are duplicates.